# Make Selenide undetectable using firefox (Kotlin)

Tags: selenium, kotlin, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenide

while trying to use Selenide with Firefox driver in order to pull data out of HTML its being detected by websites.
I've tried many things across the internet but still no luck.
This is my code so far:

```
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BeforeAll
        fun setUpAll() {
            val options = FirefoxOptions()
            val profile = options.profile
            profile.setPreference("dom.webdriver.enabled", false)
            profile.setPreference("useAutomationExtension", false)
            profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0")
            options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
            profile.setPreference("excludeSwitches", "enable-automation")
            Configuration.browser = "firefox"
            Configuration.browserSize = "1280x800"
            Configuration.browserCapabilities = options
            SelenideLogger.addListener("allure", AllureSelenide())
        }
    }
    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        open("https://www.gmail.com/")
        `$`(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']")).setValue("someemail").pressEnter()
    }
```

Please advice, thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure `options.profile` have support for `useAutomationExtension`, `excludeSwitches` and `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`?

Comment: jstola: The code that you can see in the table, Gmail send me a message that my browser is not secure
Undetected Selenium: I've seen it across this site what can I do please? Set up an idea project using kotlin with selenide default configurations

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.